# Drawing in GUI from other classes

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to create a card game on the GUI. In the process I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JComponent component = new JComponent(){
      public void paintComponent(Graphics graph) {
        draw(graph);
      }
    };

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(component);

}

public static void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(0,50,100,150);
}
```

This works, but when I try to put the same thing(without main) into another class's constructor, nothing shows up on the GUI when I initialize an instance of that class in main(The JButtons work). Is there a way to draw on the GUI from another class?

I'm trying to create a field class that draws something like a checker board, and a Card class that are rectangles and can be moved on the field by JButtons.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved by having a draw method in your other class. Let's call it Card like you mentioned.

```
public class Card {
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // draw your card here
    }
}
```

And in your main all you need is to create at least one card object and simply call `card.draw(g);` in the main draw method. I assume you will use multiple cards, so I advice using an array here. I hope you get the idea.

Avoid creating multiple JFrames, stick with one if possible.